# How to get selected data in React?

Tags: reactjs

When I selected items, veri functions not running. Why isn't it working, what can  I do?

```
class User extends Component {

    veri = (e) => {                   //functions
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <div className="container anaclass">
                     <div className="dropdown" style={{display:"inline"}}  >
                        <button className="btn btn-primary px-5" data-toggle="dropdown"  >ligler</button>

                        <div className="dropdown-menu" id="lig"  onChange={this.veri} >
                            <a href="" className="dropdown-item">İtalya</a>
                            <a href="" className="dropdown-item">İngiltere</a>
                            <a href="" className="dropdown-item">Almanya</a>
                        </div>
                    </div> 


                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: It looks like there's `onChange` on a div. Did you mean for this to be an `<select>` menu with `<option>`s?

Comment: `onChange` is not a valid attribute for a `<div/>`. You need to put an `onClick` on each of the `<a/>` dropdown options, or convert this dropdown into a `<select/>` with `<option/>`s

Answer (score 0):

You can check console.log(e.target) to see what you're receiving. And you should call the veri function with an onClick rather than with an onChange.